# Can't boot Ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 5000 series

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, dell

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Inspiron Laptop and it was working great. I turned off secureboot and it was letting me boot to Ubuntu until I booted back too Windows, and now the GRUB screen won't come up and I always boot straight to Windows 10. I tried running boot repair from a live USB stick, but got the output [here](https://paste2.org/Cd0F3zLe). I have been stuck for a while and tried a few different fixes but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly have enabled Legacy mode or something other than UEFI. Revert to UEFI and you should be able to launch grub.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when your boot order is set to windows boot first. It has to be Ubuntu, in order to Grub take over the boot, so you can choose the OS.
If it's not the case, maybe grub is corrupted. Then yoy should boot from a live usb and repair grub.
In order to repair grub, follow up this tutorial:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair